# ReactJS - ToDo app, remove items from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. ReactJS is pretty new to me, so I need some help into the right direction.

What I want to achieve is when the span is clicked on a single list item, it should remove the list item. I created a removeHandler function on the parent component, and tried passing the function down via props.

The code compiles fine, but when I try to run it in the browser I get this in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
at createTasks (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:9556:26)
at Array.map (native)
at Object.render (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:9562:33)
at file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:13530:21
at measureLifeCyclePerf (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:12809:12)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:13529:25)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:13556:32)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:13480:36)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:13458:10)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (file:///C:/Users/Laurens/Desktop/ReactJS/output/myCode.js:13379:12)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong,
I have these two components:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
return {
    items: [] // De initial state (state wanneer het component gemount wordt) voor items wordt aangemaakt en is per definitie leeg.
  };
},
addItem: function(e) {
  var itemArray = this.state.items;

  if(this._inputElement.value){ // Controleer of er een value is gepost. Een lege taak willen we immers niet toevoegen aan de todoItems.
  itemArray.push( // Zoja, push dan een een nieuw item aan de itemArray.
    {
      text: this._inputElement.value, // De text van het volgende item is gelijk aan wat er in het textfield is ingevoerd.
      key: Date.now() // De key moet uniek zijn, dus gebruiken we Date.now() voor een zoe goed als unieke key.
    }
  );
}

this.setState({
  items: itemArray // Vervolgens update de state items met itemArray.
});

this._inputElement.value = "";// Het textfield wordt weer leeg gemaakt.

e.preventDefault();
},
handleRemove: function(id){
const remainder = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
  if(item.key !== id) return item;
});

this.setState({
  items: remainder
});
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="todoListMain">
      <div className="header">
        <h3>ToDo lijst webapp</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
          <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a} placeholder="enter task">
          </input>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <TodoItems remove={this.handleRemove} entries={this.state.items}/>
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

And the following:

```
    var TodoItems = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;

    function createTasks(item) {
      return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}<span onClick={this.props.handleRemove(item.key)}>X</span></li>
    }

    var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks);
    return (
      <ul className="theList">
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `<span onClick={this.props.handleRemove(item.key)`
to `<span onClick={this.props.remove(item.key)`  the props name is remove not handleRemove

and do `todoEntries.map(createTasks, this);` also `this.props.remove.bind(this, item.key)`

Comment: While this is true, it would not cause the error listed above. "this" is not bound correctly as well.

Comment: yup "this" is undefined

Comment: i noticed, it's probably because it is in a function.. How to work around this?

Comment: try todoEntries.map(createTasks, this);

Comment: I tried removing the function and my current code works, but there is one thing... It fires the handleremove function whenever the add button is clicked? And it doesn't fire the handleremove function when the span is clicked somehow, but it's not giving errors  var listItems = todoEntries.map((item) => <li key={item.key}>{item.text}<span onClick={this.props.remove(item.key)}>X</span></li>);

Comment: do this.props.remove.bind(this, item.key)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143365/discussion-between-david-and-laurens-makel).

Answer (score 1):

```
var TodoItems = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var todoEntries = this.props.entries;

      function createTasks(item) {
        return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}<span onClick={() => this.props.remove(item.key)}>X</span></li>;
      }

      var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks,this);
      return (
        <ul className="theList">
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What David said is true, but you need to do an additional thing, so I'm copying David's answer along with the fix:

change `<span onClick={this.props.handleRemove(item.key)` to `<span onClick={this.props.remove.bind(this)(item.key)` the props name is remove not handleRemove