# Need help understanding .map and .filter in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

Code in question = ([My Gist](https://gist.github.com/DravionV/ee4e90461499c6ae8437a8a7fabd19c1))

I've seen a couple of questions similar to this one but I wasn't able to derive an answer for my situation from them:

([Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776359/reactjs-todo-app-remove-items-from-list))

My question is how are the following two 'console.log()'s correctly displaying:

```
console.log(delTodos[index]); // returns object called
console.log('the above is index ' + index); // returns appropiate index of object called
```

But when I use

```
const newArr = delTodos.filter( () => delTodos[index] === index);
this.setState({ todos: newArr});
```

It removes the entire array from displaying.

My theory of what is going on is:

So im dealing with 2 loops; (MAP x 3) and (FILTER x 3) for each map iteration.

1st MAP loop = ((index = 0)(.filter === index)); //returns true since filter*3

2nd MAP loop = ((index = 1)(.filter === index)); //returns true since filter*3

3rd MAP loop = (index = 2(.filter === index)); //returns true since filter*3

and if the loops are working like whats described above then using !== will never delete anything because the comparison of the filter will always be false.

Shouldn't the above console logs at least display three times with every click since the map is a loop function and is causing the filter loop to be equal atleast three times?

What im trying to do is filter out the single index that is displayed/described by the two console logs above. Not the entire array.

Comment: For your code here:`.filter( () => delTodos[index] === index)`, don't forget to pass in the value and the index (if you need it).  For this line to work correctly, you'd need to do: `.filter( (value, index) => delTodos[index] === index)` ... or just `... ( _ , index) => ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering out any objects in `delTodos` that are not equal to that objects index in the array. That's a problem since your array is a list of objects and not integers.

To return the array as it is, but with the item at `index` removed, try:

```
const newArr = delTodos.filter( (v, i) => i !== index);
```

`v` (as in *value*) represents the item in each iteration and `i` the current iteration of the loop. You want to remove the item where `i` is equal to `index`.

*note:* we are not actually using `v` for anything, but `i` has to be the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Your code worked exactly as I needed the moment I changed '===' to '!==' thankyou very much; however Im not understanding the '(v,i)' portion. I get that 'i' is the iterator in this portion 'i' !== index... but I dont understand the 'i' inside of (v, i)

Comment: @Ghoyos, yes of course. My bad with the `===`, I just copied your code and didn't see the mistake.

Comment: @Ghoyos, for the `(v,i)` part, take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. Basically it is a fat arrow function where the first parameter represents the current item and the second the index of the current item in the array. See it like `function(v, i) {...`

Comment: function(object , object[index]) => object[index] !== index); so like this?

Comment: @Ghoyos, if this is not clear yet, take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xs7jsevs/. Read the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Filter will remove any item in the array when the return is false. So for example (i'm guessing the functionality you want):

```
var todos = ['eat', 'sleep', 'rave', 'repeat'];
var delTodo = 'sleep';

var result = todos.filter(todo => todo === delTodo);
```

result will be = `['eat', 'rave', 'repeat']`

or deleting an array of items:

```
var todos = ['eat', 'sleep', 'rave', 'repeat'];
var delTodos = ['sleep', 'eat'];

// Checks each todo against the ones to delete, and if it exists
// returns false so it can be removed
var result = todos.filter(todo => !delTodos.some(d => d === todo));
```

result will be = `['rave', 'repeat']`

Comment: Thankyou for the link, Someone gave a clear answer right before you did wich is why they got the check but I up-voted your response, it is very helpfull.